# PyQt4 as dependency in setup script

Tags: python, dependencies, pyqt4, setuptools, setup.py

I'm creating a `setup.py` install script for my upcoming PyQt application. The PyQt modules are all spelled with camel case as opposed to the standard module name conventions, and I can't find what name to use in the setup script.

What is the name of the PyQt4 module to be used in the `install_requires` field of `setup()`?

Answer (score 0):

A search of the Python Package Index reveals it's actually `python-qt`. Annoying, but I suppose it works.

EDIT: Actually, it's not. See the comments below.

Comment: `python-qt` is a (quote from pypi) "Python compatibility wrapper for Qt Bindings". It's certainly not what you want to declare the dependency on `PyQt4`.

Comment: @sebastian I don't suppose you have a replacement answer?

Comment: Nope - I guess you could simply add "PyQt4". In any case, since there is no Pip-installable version of pyqt, it will only prevent installations of your package in case pyqt is not installed.

Comment: Having `PyQt4` won't work as intended. I'll just leave it blank and declare it in the installation guide.